# How to use the matlab function tar?

Tags: matlab, tar

I am now want to compress a file name File1.txt which is in the current folder. When I try to use the function tar like:
tar('File1.tgz','File1.txt');
Some error happen.

Undefined variable "File1" or function "File1.tgz".
Error in tar (line 1)
tar(File1.tgz,'File1.txt');

Is it any incorrect part of this?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: "Some error happen" is the message you got on MATLAB?

Comment: If `tar(File1.tgz,'File1.txt');` is exactly what you wrote, you forgot to put `' '` around the name of the .tgz file.

Comment: Hello, I make some mistake here, and I do not miss the ' '. But it still can not work.

Comment: the matlab still give the message
`Attempt to execute SCRIPT tar as a function:
C:\Users\LamMork\Desktop\Compress\tar.m

Error in tar (line 1)
tar('File1.tgz','File1.txt')`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `''`.

Try:

```
tar('File1.tgz','File1.txt');
```

In my MatlabR2013a it works without problems.

---

Matlab example:

%Tar all files in the current directory to the file backup.tgz

tar('backup.tgz','.');

Comment: It still can not work. 

Attempt to execute SCRIPT tar as a function:
C:\Users\LamMork\Desktop\Compress\tar.m

Error in tar (line 1)
tar('File1.tgz','File1.txt');

Comment: I have try different matlab version, but the error message
`Attempt to execute SCRIPT tar as a function:
C:\Users\LamMork\Desktop\Compress\tar.m

Error in tar (line 1)
tar('File1.tgz','File1.txt');` is still here.

Is it I put the original file in the wrong folder?

Comment: I see that your file name is 'tar.m' and it can be a problem. Rename it for example 'myTar.m' and it should work.